# Unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, sed

I looked at other similar questions but the answers did not help me. I am new to bash and probably have a syntax error in my script but I can't figure out where. I was trying to update users in the example.conf file every time this script is run. Each user has a name.pub file.

```
VAR1=$( ls  | grep ".pub" |sed "s/.pub//g")
VAR2="@demo_project_users = "
res=$VAR2$VAR1
sed  "s/@demo_project_users = .*/$res/g" example.conf
```

This is producing the `Unterminated 's' command` error.

Edit: I have these files in a folder

```
aaaaaaaaaa.pub  eboh.pub      get_usernames.sh  mmusterfrau.pub  plom.pub   rrein.pub  update_users.sh
dboh.pub        example.conf  leni.pub          mmustermann.pub  rcall.pub  tani.pub
```

and I want to get all user names (without .pub) in one row with a space inbetween, like this

```
@demo_project_users = (... all  names here)
```

Comment: Please try to add \ before spaces like `s/@demo_project_users\ =\ .*/$res/g`

Comment: *"Each user has a name.pub file"* so likely `VAR1` is a multi-line string?

Comment: @binarysta The spaces in the pattern is not an issue.

Comment: @steeldriver if I echo VAR1, the output is in one line

Comment: @FiloménaPetržlénová Yes, but try `echo "$VAR1"`. Remember to _always_ quote variable expansions.

Comment: @Kusalananda wow thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `grep` is likely matching more than one filename, which gives a value in `$res` that contains newlines. GNU `sed` would complain exactly the way that you describe when using a replacement string that contains literal newlines.

Don't use `grep` to filter the output of `ls`.  If you want to get all names in he current directory matching the pattern `*.pub`, use

```
filenames=( *.pub )
```

This would create an array containing all names that matches the given pattern.

Then:

```
sed 's/\(@demo_project_users = \).*/\1'"${filenames[*]%.pub}"'/g' example.conf
```

The `"${filenames[*]%.pub}"` expansion will expand to a single string consisting of each of the filenames in the `filenames` array, delimited by spaces (or whatever the first character of `$IFS` happens to be; a space by default), and with the suffix string `.pub` removed from each one.

It's the `"${filenames[*]}"` bit that expands to the space-delimited string, and its the `%.pub` bit that removes the `.pub` suffix from each filename.

Comment: I made an edit, I need to process multiple filenames, not just one

Comment: @FiloménaPetržlénová I made an update.

Comment: thank you, your answer helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

The substitution of `$res` into the command is done by the shell. If there's a slash in the value, sed has no way to know that it isn't the end marker for the `s` command. Likewise sed will interpret any backslash or ampersand in `$res` as a special character.

If backslashes and ampersands cannot possibly appear in `$res` and there's another character that you know cannot possibly appear as well, use that character as a separator. For example:

```
sed  "s~@demo_project_users = .*~$res~g" example.conf
```

Alternatively, quote special characters by adding a backslash before them.

```
quoted_res=$(printf %s "$res" | sed 's/[\\\/&]/\\&/g')
sed  "s/@demo_project_users = .*/$quoted_res/g" example.conf
```